# getting the rowindex of a deleted row in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, object-reference

following is the issue.

I want to get the row index and column index of the deleted row of datagridview for some calculations and updations.but the error i keep getting is object reference not set to an instance of an object.
i have written the code in the rows removed event of the data gridview.heres the code.

```
Try


    delflag = True
    Dim quant As Integer
    If dgsalesitem.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = 0 Then
        quant = dgsalesitem.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    Else
        quant = dgsalesitem.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    End If
    UpdateStock(dgsalesitem.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString, dgsalesitem.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString, dgsalesitem.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString, quant, False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the `UserDeletingRow` **event** when user is about to delete the row:

```
Private Sub dgsalesitem_UserDeletingRow(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles dgsalesitem.UserDeletingRow    
 Try
   delflag = True
   Dim quant As Integer
   If e.Row.Cells(0).Value = 0 Then
      quant = e.Row.Cells(1).Value
   Else
      quant = e.Row.Cells(0).Value
   End If
   UpdateStock(e.Row.Cells(2).Value.ToString, e.Row.Cells(9).Value.ToString, e.Row.Cells(10).Value.ToString, quant, False)
 Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
 End Try
End Sub
```

And if you want to get the `Row Index` of the row deleted, you could simply use:

```
 e.Row.Index
```

Comment: i want the deleted rows index.well i have disallowed multi select so only 1 row can be deleted.even if i use that condition for checking count the error will go,but i need the deleted row index for further calculations

Comment: Glad to be of help @vimalvasudevan. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

under `.RowsRemoved` use `e.RowIndex` to get the index of the row removed.